# Modify query string in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am currently updating our website and want to redirect from old url's to the new ones. I appliled several rewriterules to get nice urls without query strings for the new pages, this works perfectly. But i ran into problems when trying to do the following:

I want to change an url's query string from

```
www.domain.com/?content=foo
```

to

```
www.domain.com/index.php?content=bar
```

or even better, rewrite directly to the new , nice url i have already generated by rewrite rules:

to

```
www.domain.com/niceurl
```

in the .htaccess file using a RewriteRule.

I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} content=foo
RewriteRule content=bar$ content=foo [L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} content=foo
RewriteRule niceurl$ content=foo [L]
```

and a lot of other variations, i just can't get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Does `www.domain.com/niceurl` work for you already? Do you have other rules to support it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redirect, i.e. tell the client to forget about the old URL and fetch the new shiny URL instead, you must look for the old one ([`RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) pattern `/` and [`RewriteCond`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) `QUERY_STRING`) and then redirect [`R`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) to the new URL

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} content=foo
RewriteRule ^$ /niceurl [R,L]
```